# Проблема со стикерами Aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram

Всем привет, хотел создать стикер пак, но вы не выходит код ниже

```
async def sticker_set(msg:types.Message):
    await bot.create_new_sticker_set(
    user_id=msg.from_user.id, 
    name = "what_den_things",
    title = "What Denis thinks",
    png_sticker = "boring.png", 
    emojis = ""
    
    )
```

Comment: Что не выходит? С этим кодом что-то не так?

Comment: Он выдает ошибку badrequest:(